# Trouble Finding Dominating Integrable Functions for Limiting Integrals

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I'm currently working on some practice exercises in preparation for an exam in a probability theory class and the section on dominated convergence is giving me some trouble. Below are three exercises. I feel like I have the first one right, but then the next two have been driving me crazy. Any help would be much appreciated.

1.) $lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-t/n} dt$

Answer: Here, since t is bounded by [0,1], as n goes to infinity, $e^{-t/n}$ converges to 1 (i.e. $e^o$). Thus, we can find dominance in:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-t/n} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}(1)$, or just simply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$, which is integrable. Thus,

$lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-t/n} dt$ = $\int_0^1 lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-t/n} dt$ = $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ = 2

Correct?

2.) $lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{r^n}{1+r^{n+2}} dr$

Answer:

Here, finding the dominated integrable function is what I'm getting caught on. It seems easy to say first that clearly $\frac{r^n}{1+r^{n+2}} \le \frac{r^n}{r^{n+2}}$

And we can simplify the right side to $\frac{1}{r^2}$, which is not integrable on our interval..

3.) $lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt[n]x}{1+x^2} dx$

Answer: Basically the same problem here. First instinct is to say $\frac{\sqrt[n]x}{1+x^2} \le \frac{\sqrt[n]x}{x^2}$

As n goes to infinity, the nth root of any x will converge to 1, so that we can again simplify the right side of the inequality as $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which same as before is not integrable on our interval..

Again, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct. For the others, we can decompose the integral to $\int_0^1+ \int_1^{\infty}$, and for each integrand find a dominating function. I will work out the second one (the third one is analogous).

$$\int_0^{\infty}f_n(r)dr = \int_0^1 f_n(r)dr + \int_1^{\infty} f_n(r)dr$$

On $[0,1]$, $f_n(r)\to 0$ almost everywhere (it converges to $0$ except at $r=1$) and:

$$0\le f_n(r)\le \frac1{1+r^2} \in L^1$$

So we get $\lim \int_0^1 f_n(r)dr = 0$.

On $[1,\infty)$, $f_n(r)\to \frac1{r^2}$, and:

$$0\le f_n(r)\le \frac{1}{r^2} \in L^1$$

So $\lim \int_1^{\infty}f_n(r)dr = \int_1^{\infty}\frac1{r^2}dr = 1$

Therefore $\lim \int_0^{\infty}f_n(r)dr = 0+1=1$.

Comment: @Archetupon you're welcome!

Comment: @Archetupon by the way, if you find that this answers your question, click on the green mark next to my answer.

Comment: I did but I guess I'm too new here :(